# Are dates consecutive

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a simple table representing a customer number and when they made a purchase. I need to know when any given customer has made a purchase on consecutive dates and what those dates were. The number of consecutive dates is irrelevant.

So in this example

```
+----------+--------+
| Customer |  Date  |
+----------+--------+
|      123 | 21-Jan |
|      123 | 24-Jan |
|      345 | 21-Jan |
|      345 | 23-Jan |
|      345 | 24-Jan |
|      123 | 26-Jan |
|      123 | 27-Jan |
+----------+--------+
```

I need to return the following:

```
+----------+--------+
| Customer |  Date  |
+----------+--------+
|      123 | 26-Jan |
|      123 | 27-Jan |
|      345 | 23-Jan |
|      345 | 24-Jan |
+----------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a modified gaps and islands problem. One solution is to use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        grp = DATEADD(DAY, -ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Customer ORDER BY Date), Date)
    FROM tbl
),
CteFinal AS(
    SELECT *,
        cnt = COUNT(Customer) OVER(PARTITION BY Customer, grp)
    FROM Cte
)
SELECT
    Customer, Date
FROM CteFinal
WHERE cnt > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT Customer , [Date] 
FROM Table T
WHERE
Exists( SELECT 1 FROM Table WHERE [Date] = DATEADD(day,1,T.Date) OR [Date] = DATEADD(day, -1,T.Date))
```

you will need to format your dates properly if it contains time